# Open direct message channel to a user with a Slack Workspace token?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm working on a new [Workspace app](https://api.slack.com/workspace-apps-preview) for Slack. I have a use case where I need to send notifications to users in Slack, through a direct message (or IM). Since the [chat.postMessage](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) endpoint requires a channel ID, I can get the existing IM channels using [conversations.list](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.list) and send them the notification.

However, if the user hasn't yet opened an IM channel from their side, I need to create one. It seems that neither Web API endpoints ([conversations.open](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.open) or [im.open](https://api.slack.com/methods/im.open)) support Workspace tokens. I keep getting *not_allowed_token_type* error response. I can create a public channel with [conversations.create](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.create), but that's not what I need.

Is there another to open an IM channel to a user when using a Workspace token?

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue. The docs for [chat.postMessage](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) say a Workspace token/app should be able to just pass a User ID for the `channel` parameter, but this is returning `no_permission` for anyone except the app installer. I also tried `im.open` first, and I'm getting `not_allowed_token_type` for all users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Took me awhile to figure this out. You need to add/request the [conversations.app_home:create](https://api.slack.com/scopes/conversations.app_home:create) scope to your permissions. Then you can just specify the user ID as the channel arg in a `chat.postMessage` call.

Comment: Nice catch! Must be new, since their developer support told me at the time they had not yet decided how they were going to implement it. There's still a catch though: the user must have opened the `app_home` channel manually before the messages can go through. Still no way to open that channel from the app side, but that's seems to be a design decision on their part.

Comment: This has been working for my workspace without users having to open the bot window first. That's also what the docs imply, that this is a substitute for im.open

Comment: That's weird. It doesn't in mine. Even after reinstalling the app with the new permission.

Comment: does not exist in mine app can you help how to find it